# In python how to have two file iterators iterating over lines at different rates?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen lots of questions and answers similar to [Iterating over two text files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745746/iterating-over-two-text-files-in-python)

This is not what I want.

I want to do something like:

```
with open(file_1) as in_file_1:
    with open(file_2) as in_file_2:
        cur_line_1 = file_1.nextLine()
        cur_line_2 = file_2.nextLine()
        while(some_while_condition(cur_line_1)):
            if some_condition(cur_line_1):
                cur_line_2 = file_2.nextLine()
                print(some_func(cur_line_1, cur_line_2))
            cur_line_1 = file_1.nextLine()
```

Comment: you almost got it, instead of `nextLine` do `readline`

Comment: How do you iterate over an iterable in an ad-hoc fashion?

Comment: @Nullman ah ok. I see it now in the docs and feel silly. Should I close the question?

Comment: i would say yes, but im not sure what the official etiquette is

Comment: ok well i won't close because when I try closing none of the reasons for closing match this. Unless someone tells me otherwise, ill leave it open. If you want to answer it ill accept. otherwise i will answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, instead of `nextLine` do `readline`
you can also combine both `with` statements:

```
with open(file_1) as in_file_1, open(file_2) as in_file_2:
    cur_line_1 = file_1.readline()
    cur_line_2 = file_2.readline()
    while(some_while_condition(cur_line_1)):
        if some_condition(cur_line_1):
            cur_line_2 = file_2.readline()
            print(some_func(cur_line_1, cur_line_2))
        cur_line_1 = file_1.readline()
```